# Why I cannot put a asp:RequiredFieldValidator on a asp:HiddenField?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

In fact, that hidden field could be important, and a user can edit the cache/code directly from browser and send the form without it.

Why I can't use a requiredfieldvalidator? Is there another control to use for it or automatically .NET check all HiddenField in the postback?

Answer (score 1):

A validator is used for normal expected user input through the browser.
Hidden fields should be checked manually when there's a necessity for that.

Answer (score 1):

> a user can edit the cache/code directly from browser and send the form
>   without it

That's true. But why do you think it's safe if you add a validator? Adding a RequiredFieldValidator essentially adds a **JavaScript** check before the form is submitted, which is not safe either.

Never trust the data comes from the clients. You should always check them at sever side. Client side checks are for better user experiences only.

Comment: That's not true. Adding a RequiredFieldValidator adds control also to the server side (which I can check only with the single **Page.Validate();** method). That's annoying : adding more further controls, when they should check in one method :)